# Append a tuple to a dataframe as a row

Tags: pandas, append, row, tuples

I am looking for a solution to add rows to a dataframe. Here is the data I have : 
A grouped object ( obtained by grouping a dataframe on month and year i.e in this grouped object key is [month,year] and value is all the rows / dates in that month and year).

I want to extract all the month , year combinations and put that in a new dataframe. **Issue** : When I iterate over the grouped object, month, row is a tuple, so I converted the tuple into a list and added it to a dataframe using thye append command. Instead of getting added as rows : 
1 2014
2 2014
3 2014
it got added in one column 
0 1
1 2014
0 2
1 2014
0 3
1 2014
...

I want to store these values in a new dataframe. Here is how I want the new dataframe to be :
     month  year
     1     2014
     2     2014
     3     2014

I tried converting the tuple to list and then I tried various other things like pivoting. Inputs would be really helpful.

Here is the sample code :

```
    df=df.groupby(['month','year'])
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for key, value in df:
            print "type of key is:",type(key)
            print "type of list(key) is:",type(list(key))
            df = df.append(list(key))
    print df
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do the groupby the resulting MultiIndex is available as:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2014, 42], [1, 2014, 44], [2, 2014, 23]], columns=['month', 'year', 'val'])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   month  year  val
0      1  2014   42
1      1  2014   44
2      2  2014   23

In [13]: g = df.groupby(['month', 'year'])

In [14]: g.grouper.result_index
Out[14]:
MultiIndex(levels=[[1, 2], [2014]],
           labels=[[0, 1], [0, 0]],
           names=['month', 'year'])
```

Often this will be sufficient, and you won't need a DataFrame. If you do, one way is the following:

```
In [21]: pd.DataFrame(index=g.grouper.result_index).reset_index()
Out[21]:
   month  year
0      1  2014
1      2  2014
```

*I thought there was a method to get this, but can't recall it.*

If you really want the tuples you can use `.values` or `to_series`:

```
In [31]: g.grouper.result_index.values
Out[31]: array([(1, 2014), (2, 2014)], dtype=object)

In [32]: g.grouper.result_index.to_series()
Out[32]:
month  year
1      2014    (1, 2014)
2      2014    (2, 2014)
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks, Andy.That seemed to be working. I have used R's dplyr package and that seems a lot easier and more intutive  than pandas, is there any similar package in python pandas ? I found a package called pandas-ply but looks like they are still working on it. Have you used this or anything similar?

Comment: @UdayShankar I'm not sure. I think the reason this feels clunky is that there is there is probably a neater way to do whatever it is you're doing - without getting into the internals. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: could also do `g.groups.keys()` to get the tuples.

Answer (score 1):

You had initially declared both the groupby and empty dataframe as `df`. Here's a modified version of your code that allows you to append a tuple as a dataframe row.

```
g=df.groupby(['month','year'])
df = pd.DataFrame()
for (key1,key2), value in g:
    row_series = pd.Series((key1,key),index=['month','year'])
    df = df.append(row_series, ignore_index = True)
print df
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want are the unique values, you could use `drop_duplicates`

```
In [29]: df[['month','year']].drop_duplicates()
Out[29]: 
   month  year
0      1  2014
2      2  2014
```

Comment: thanks chrisb, but in my case this may not be the solution I am looking for.